# What is the correct way to manage Graphics2D settings?

Tags: java

When I temporarily change a setting in a Graphics2D object do I need to save and restore the original setting? Example:

```
Color saveColor = graphicsContext.getColor();
graphicsContext.setColor( Color.RED );  // is this code...
graphicsContext.performSomeOperation();
graphicsContext.setColor( saveColor );  // ... necessary?
```

All the examples I have looked just set the color and perform the operation, without the save/restore logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
Graphics2D safeCopy = yourCurrentGraphics.create();
safeCopy.setColor(Color.BLUE);
drawBlueThings(safeCopy);
safeCopy.dispose();
```

This way, yourCurrentGraphics will be at the exactly same state before you change the copy parameters.

Comment: Good suggestion. What is the advantage of .dispose()?

Comment: This is the solution, your graphics will keep untouched by settings changes.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, you should save and restore the affine transform setting (because the same graphics object will be used to paint multiple components), but other settings can be usually set without restoring (they will be overwritten anyway).

Comment: Got it. For example, in my paint method I see that the color is set to gray-51. I explicitly change it to red, but the next time my paint method is called it's back to gray-51.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor-java.awt.Color-) (highlighting by me):

> public abstract void setColor(Color c)
>
> Sets this graphics context's current color to the specified color. **All
>   subsequent graphics operations using this graphics context use this
>   specified color**.

So yes, you should reset it unless you are sure that either the graphicsContext will not be re-used later on or the next operation will not rely on the color currently set (e.g. sets the color itself).

I don't know which examples you were looking at, but maybe those were focusing more on the operation itself and less on the potential side effects. But that's just speculation.